# Table Refresh, Every Second

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, refresh

```
<html>
<body>
<body bgcolor="33FF00">
<script language = "JavaScript">
//-----------------Created Variables Here------------------


timeLeft = 30                                                       //this is counted down from until it hits 0
points = 0                                                          //this is the points system that is added to by 10 each time a duck is clicked


// ----------------Duck Or Sky element-----------------


function duSky(){                                                   //This is a function to tell add points to the points variable if the user clicks a duck.
duckNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)
if(duckNum<10){document.write("<img src=images/skyTile.jpg>")}
else{document.write("<img src='images/duckTile.jpg' onClick='duckClick()'")}
}


</script>


<center><img src=images/duckHuntTitle.gif><br>                  <!Duck Hunt title gif, no background so you can see the background of the page, also centered>



<div name = "tableDiv">                                         <!Named the table "TableDiv" so that I can refer to it at a later date. This was to try and make my job of refreshing easier>   
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>

    </tr>                                                       <!Inside of all the table boxes there is a function that designates whether inside will be a duck or sky tile>
    <tr>                                                        <!This is the duck table that is exactly 1000px wide by 400px height. This is created by 10 200px by 200px boxes, two rows of 5 boxes>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    <td> <script> duSky() </script> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<form name="score">
Points <input type="text" name="pointsscored" readonly="readonly">  <!This is the box that is centered that displays the points the player has got, also is now readonly so no tweaking is allowed>
</form>

<form name="timer">
Time <input type="text" name="timeBox" readonly="readonly">         <!This is the timer box that is centered as well that displays how long the player has left and is readonly>
</form>
</center>


<script language = "JavaScript">                                        //Returns the script to JavaScript to allow for functions to be used that are related to the HTML previous to this


document.timer.timeBox.value = timeLeft                             //Displays the time left before the game has even started and been clicked so the player immediately knows the time that they have to play with


function timeDecrease(){                                            //This is the timer function that reduces the timer by a second each time to make the game slowly time out after 30 seconds
setInterval(function(){timeLeft--                                   //I am still working on the refresh function but hopefully it will be corrected to make the table refresh with every 1000 miliseconds
document.timer.timeBox.value=timeLeft;
//document.tableDiv.reload(true)                                      //trying to get the reload function to work.
 },1000);                                                                 //1000 miliseconds, therefore it is 1 second
}


while(timeLeft < 0){alert("Timeeeeeees Up, you scored: ", points ,"points! well done Duck Slayer!")}    //Alert to signify the end of the game.


// ----------------Function for clicking the duck-----------------


function duckClick(){
points = points + 10;
document.score.pointsscored.value = points;                            //when the player clicks the duck, points will be added to the points box
}


</script>
<center>


<form name = "playButton"> 
<button type="button" onClick = "timeDecrease()">Play!</button>     <!This is    the on click function that starts the game/countdown feature>


</center>
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

I have a problem with getting my graph to work. I am currently working on making a simple point and click game and I need the table to refresh to make the images become randomized in the position. The idea is that it refreshes every second, giving the appearance of true randomization from a previous section of the script. The problem is that I can't get the table to refresh even though I have set a div tag and I am using the reload function. I am hoping that you  can help me find a solution to this.

Also the website doesn't recognise the `document.tableDiv.reload(true)` part but I don't understand how to get the table to refresh with every second that goes past.

P.S if you haven't guessed I am awful at coding but hope to get better.

Comment: why do you call the function "duSky()" in every table cell?

Comment: afaik, `reload`is only defined on the `document` object ( you need a source to reload it from, right ?). however, the design is doubtful in general: where do you define `timeLeft`? how do you cancel the interval function without a handle? doesn't your interval function lack a termination condition? note that in case of a reload, you're reloading the script content as well and lose the execution state.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will put the whole script in a response I just didn't know whether it was unecessary clutter.

Comment: Added the whole script to the document. Sorry about that. Really need help on this. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery, it will make your life easier as selectors mean you won't have to repeat so much code.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Assign all of the `td` elements to run `duSky()` function in a class -- we'll also take the script out of the `td` as we're going to run it from jQuery's `document.ready` function:

```
<td class='dusky'></td>
```

Next, we make a function to assign each `td` with the output of `duSky()`:

```
<script>
// This function takes every table cell with dusky class and inserts output of duSky() into it
$(document).ready(function refresh(){
    $('.dusky).each(function(){
        this.html = duSky();
    })
})
</script>
```

Finally, we make it refresh every 5 seconds:

```
<script>
// Make our refresh script run every 5 seconds
setInterval(refresh, 5000);
</script>
```

Note: I can't test this where I am, code may not be 100% correct, but this is on the right lines. If you change it and it helps, please give me the right code so I can edit the post and give future readers an easier ride.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm about to try this out. You have no idea how much you've helped me out if this works. If it doesn't I still appreciate the effort you put in :)

Comment: Sorry to be a complete noobie but would I put the "<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>" where I currently put the script language or would I have to put it below it. Or just use it instead of script language.

Comment: You put that above the function I just gave you as your site will need to load jQuery before using its functions. I'd suggest putting all scripts in the `<head>` of your page.

Comment: Apparently I have an unterminated string constant :/ It comes from the function that inserts output of duSky. All the same it looks as though everything is working well. I really appreciate the time you are spending helping me.